# Reachable vertices in directed graph made from vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, graph, vertices

I'm working on a simple programming assignment for my studies and I've encountered a problem. The assignment has a predefined header which cannot be modified, so I have to use the structures that are set, making the problem more complicated than it should be.

I need to implement a function that returns a vector of all vertices reachable from the start vertex. That would be a simple task if I could use a more complex structure for it, but the whole graph is represented as a vector of vectors, leaving me stumped with how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The graph structure means that for example graph that's `{{1,2,3}, {3}, {3}, {}}` means that vertex 0 leads to vertices 1,2,3; vertex 1 leads to 3, vertex 2 leads to 3, vertex 3 leads nowhere.

**graph.hpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

/*
 * Struct representing graph, that is, vertices and edges between the vertices.
 * Vertices are identified with indices, where 0 stands for 1st added vertex,
 * 1 stands for 2nd added vertex, 2 stands for 3rd added vertex, etc...
 *
 * The edges between vertices are directed.
 */
struct graph {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> connections;
};

// Other functions manipulating the graph here

/*
 * Return vertices that are reachable from given vertex.
 * That is, the vertex itself,
            all vertices connected to the given vertex,
            all vertices connected to these vertices,
            etc...
 *
 * Can only be called with existing vertex.
 */
std::vector<int> reachable_vertices(const graph& g, int vertex);
```

I've tried a kind of naive brute force approach but it doesn't work.

**graph.cpp**

```
#include "graph.hpp"

// Other functions manipulating the graph here

std::vector<int> reachable_vertices(const graph& g, int vertex) {
    if (g.connections.size() < vertex) {
        return{};
    }
    std::vector<int> reachables;
    for (auto vert : g.connections[vertex]) {
        if (vert > vertex) {
            reachables = reachable_vertices(g, vert);
        }
    }
    reachables.push_back(vertex);
    std::sort(reachables.begin(), reachables.end());
    reachables.erase(std::unique(reachables.begin(), reachables.end()), reachables.end());
    return reachables;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your question ?

Comment: @H.G How to implement the reachable_vertices function so it correctly returns the correct vector

Comment: What's wrong with the one that you included in your question ?

Comment: @H.G It doesn't work correctly, it was just my attempt at implementing the function. I'm not sure where exactly is the mistake, we've been supplied a test file to run that has static and randomly generated tests in it, only outputting if tests passed or failed.

Comment: "it doesn't work correctly" is vague.. if you don't know what to expect, how you will debug your function ? ... may be the bug is in the test !

Comment: @H.G. It is vague, I know, but I'm unable to provide more information sadly. The header file has description of the function and really, all I need is to have some pointers about how to tackle the problem, because the structure feels too simple for a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontier starts out with a single node. You take a node from the frontier (*if you need cycle detection*: and add it to a set of visited nodes). Perform a function on the node. Then take all the nodes that are directly reachable from that node, and add them to the frontier (*if you need cycle detection*: unless the node has been visited before). Continue until no more nodes left.

Depending on how you "add" nodes to the frontier and how you "take a node" from the frontier this is a description of a whole class of search strategies.

A queue (adding at the end, take from front) will give you a BFS, a stack (adding on top, take from top) will give you a DFS.

"Perform a function" would in your case be "add it to the set of reachable nodes".

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the reply, I can't believe I didn't realize it was that simple. I even worked on implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm in the past but I didn't realize it was the same principle.